# Tools of the trade, software implications

Tags: intellectual-property, employment

My understanding of the general legal principle of "tools of the trade" is that tools which are necessary for the exercise of a profession are the inviolate property of the tradesman and cannot be taken away from him either by bankruptcy or by employer or by the state or by anyone else. A tradesman has absolute ownership over tools necessary to conduct his trade.

For example, imagine a machinist makes a clamp at his workplace. Even if he uses company materials and time to make the clamp, the machinist still owns the clamp, because it is a generic tool, not a workpiece. If he leaves and goes to work for a different company he can take the clamp with him and he owns it forever. That is my interpretation of the "tools of the trade" principle. This would not apply to a special tool only usable at a particular employer. For example, if the tool would only work on one employers specific machine, then it is not a "tool of the trade", because it is not generic.

My question is whether this principle applies to software as well. For example, lets imagine a programmer writes a sorting algorithm. Such an algorithm is generic and can be used at any employer. Does the programmer have the right to retain and use that sorting algorithm while working for other employers because it is a "tool of the trade"?

Comment: A cursory internet search suggests that the concept applies only in bankruptcy and has no bearing on the employee/employer relationship.  Do you have any sources supporting your clamp example?

Comment: @phoog I can do internet searches too. I am looking for somebody who knows the case law.

Answer (score 5):

Your framing of the issue is basically wrong. There is an exemption, which varies from state to state, from unsecured creditors (but not creditors that take the goods as collateral) in bankruptcy and in debt collection outside of bankruptcy (not always the same exemption), for tangible personal property owned by the debtor which constitutes the debtor's tools of the trade, but that varies from state to state, is a creature of state statute (and the bankruptcy code), is not universal, and is usually limited in dollar amount.

Moreover, the exemption only applies when the tradesman actually owns the tools of his trade which is customary in some professions, but not automatic. It is only the case when the tradesman buys his own tools. There is no generic v. non-generic distinction.

In the software field, education and the public domain can always be accessed. But, intellectual property, that can be protected, that is developed for the employer, is usually work for hire and belong to the employer. This default rule is subject to the terms of the agreements between the parties entered into contractually.

Comment: To your point "varies from state to state", did you refer to the application of bankruptcy cases? I thought bankruptcy is governed by federal statute Title 11 U.S.C?

Comment: @RyanL In bankruptcy under 11 USC, a state can elect to have its citizens governed by the federal default exemptions found in 11 USC, can instead elect under 11 USC to be governed instead by the state law exemptions from creditors that apply outside of bankruptcy. Many states make the latter election.

Comment: So, say I have real properties, stocks, and member interests across 10 States at the time I file Chapter 7 to liquidate all my assets. If 4 States make latter election, my creditors will have to hire attorneys across 10 States to observe State laws in 4 States and Federal laws in the other 6 States? (sorry for my sloppy use of vocabularies)

Comment: @RyanL The exemptions that apply in the bankruptcy are governed by the state in which the bankruptcy is filed which must normally be the domicile of the bankrupt.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So, my creditors will only need to hire one attorney in the my home State and observe my home State's election?

Comment: @RyanL Your creditors will need to hire one attorney to handle the exemption issue. In actual practice, it isn't uncommon for creditors to need to hire attorneys in multiple states for other issues in, for example, a big Chapter 11 case. For example, suppose you own oil and gas rights in a dozen states whose value and existence is disputed. Your creditors probably would need to hire lawyers in each of those states to litigate those issues (as they, in fact, did in a recent oil and gas Chapter 11 that a creditor client of mine was involved in).

Comment: That's why I heard that people "in the know" will hide stuff all over the place (especially in WY and NV)..

Comment: @RyanL That is a high risk approach. If one is found  to have concealed assets or been otherwise abusive, the bankruptcy court can deny all relief and dismiss the bankruptcy petition. It  can also result in criminal penalties. And, bankruptcy cases are now audited on a mixed lottery and suspicion basis.

Comment: Thanks for this warning. I know it's a game not for the faint of the heart. As far as I know, somebody filed multiple corporate bankruptcies and now is a billionaire.

Comment: @RyanL Despite, not because of, those multiple corporate bankruptcies. That person would have been ten or twenty times wealthier if he'd put his wealth in an S&P 500 fund and taken up interpretive dancing.

Comment: Anyways, without creeping into Political scope, I once again appreciate your patience and advice.

Comment: @RyanL of course, you are not your corporation. Providing you discharged your responsibilities as a director you are no more responsible for the bankruptcy of your company than you are for your brother's bankruptcy.

Comment: @DaleM, I agree with and respect this. However, what I feel not so fair is that there are ways to get profit out of the entity, and then either shut down or bankrupt the entity to get away with liabilities and obligations.

Comment: @RyanL "what I feel not so fair is that there are ways to get profit out of the entity, and then either shut down or bankrupt the entity" There is a body of law that greatly limits this called fraudulent transfer law.

Comment: @ohwilleke, suppose I flipped a house inside an LLC. Two months after selling the house, I shut down the LLC since there's no more activity going on with that LLC. One year later, serious structural defect caused casualty. The evidence directly implicated my sloppy rehabbing practice was to blame. Whom can the home owner sue for recovery?

Comment: @RyanL It depends upon what happened to the net proceeds of the sale and other details. If they were distributed to the LLC owners the amounts transferred to the owner could probably be recovered as a fraudulent transfer, but if the deal just broke even and paid off the construction and purchase loans, probably not. If your sloppy actions were involved the LLC would have vicarious liability and you would have personal liability since you personally participated in the negligent work.

Comment: @ohwilleke, Thanks for your response. There are several points I want to touch on if you'd bear with me. First, I thought only professionals like medical doctors or CPA's only be personally liable for their professional liability? OK, let me make one clarification. If I did some handyman level work (negligent work) which doesn't require licence by law, will I still be personally liable for the casualty my work caused in the capacity of an former LLC employee?

Comment: "I thought only professionals like medical doctors or CPA's only be personally liable for their professional liability?" You were wrong. "If I did some handyman level work (negligent work) which doesn't require licence by law, will I still be personally liable for the casualty my work caused in the capacity of an former LLC employee?" Yes.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, If you are under contract (NDA & Non-Compete) and the non-compete usually includes verbiage that says anything you built while on company time, belongs to the company. Some contracts even go as far as saying that anything of IP that you build while employed by the company would belong to them as well, whether company time or not.

So that "sorting algorithm" example you gave would belong to the company.

Comment: To your point "Some contracts even go... whether company time or not.", I would add a note that some States limit the scope of this provision. For example, Washington State Statute 49.44.140: http://app.leg.wa.gov/Rcw/default.aspx?cite=49.44.140. 

For related discussion, also see this article: http://www.intellectualpropertylawfirms.com/resources/intellectual-property/patents/is-your-pre-inve

Comment: Washington State Statute 49.44.140: 
"A provision in an employment agreement which provides that an employee shall assign or offer to assign any of the employee's rights in an invention to the employer does not apply to an invention for which no equipment, supplies, facilities, or trade secret information of the employer was used and which was developed entirely on the employee's own time, unless"

Comment: Washington State Statute 49.44.140 (-con't): 
"... (a) the invention relates (i) directly to the business of the employer, or (ii) to the employer's actual or demonstrably anticipated research or development, or (b) the invention results from any work performed by the employee for the employer. Any provision which purports to apply to such an invention is to that extent against the public policy of this state and is to that extent void and unenforceable."